# Grails war and skipping tests

Tags: grails

I am looking for a way to skip tests on war command of grails. Normally this is the -DskipTests in maven, but cannot find something similar for the grails war. 
Anyone has experience with this?

Comment: `grails war --verbose` would help witness the fact mentioned by @codelark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `war` command does not depend on the `test-app` command, so the tests shouldn't run in any case.